# Display CRUD table data even after refreshing the page using ngStorage

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, crud, ng-storage

I have created this CRUD table, I can see table data being stored in web browser's  local storage in developer tools, even after editing and removing rows, but I don't know how to save and display the same data even after refreshing the page with all latest updates.

```
<head>

    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>   

</head>
```

Please see the attached code in plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/fvp2kQzxrnkgLsQ1r4i6?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues to fix.

First, you've defined vm.$storage = $localStorage yet you continue to attempt to update $localStorage when you should be updating vm.$storage.

Second, initialize your array like this:

```
vm.arr = vm.$storage.arr || [];
```

I have forked your [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/A8nGeJrFtZ02kl13dQXa?p=preview)

Comment: Got it, thanks alot for that, i was also having issues in removing the rows but got it fixed now. But now when i am updating the stored data when page is refreshed, i am getting some error , table is not updating in that way, but it gets updated if you add a row first and then update it. Can you please tell me how to fix it ? New updated plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/eoVeVLC7tBCorwy42oJ9?p=preview

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'myid' of undefined
    at Object.vm.edit (controller.js:70), when the data is saved and after refreshing, when i click on update.

Comment: got it fixed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863302/type-error-when-i-am-updating-crud-table-after-refreshing-the-page-in-angularjs/46865574#46865574