# Type Error when I am updating crud table after refreshing the page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, crud, ng-storage

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
```

When I am updating the stored data directly after refreshing the page, I am getting some error in console like TypeError: Cannot set property 'myid' of undefined at Object.vm.edit (controller.js:70), table is not updating in that way, but it gets updated if you add a row first and then update it. Can anyone help me how to fix it ? My [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/eoVeVLC7tBCorwy42oJ9?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says that data doesn't exist on controller, so you just need to initialize vm.data at the top of your controller:

```
vm.data = {};
```

Here's plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/mnRGSmEk0q9N2dSazEHL?p=preview

Another solution would be to create data object when you're adding it:

```
vm.data = {
      myid: id,
      fname: vm.arr[i].fname,
      lname: vm.arr[i].lname,
      classs: vm.arr[i].classs,
      age: vm.arr[i].age,
      fees: vm.arr[i].fees,
    };
```

Here's plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/TZmgPz2h02peBYaF0uyV?p=preview

Comment: No problem, you could accept/upvote answer if it was helpful, you could do same on your other questions on stack overflow as well.

Comment: I upvoted it, but because of less reputation it wasn't submitted.